# MATLAB Simulink: IF statement logic

Tags: matlab, if-statement, logic, system, simulink

General question, if I have MATLAB code looking like this:

```
for x=0:500
   if x <= 250
      y = 2*x+1;
   else
      y = 3*x+2;
   end
end
```

How could I have the same logic using blocks/systems in Simulink? Whenever I try switches and If blocks, I get an error like "Input Ports (1) of __ are involved in the loop.

I can share my model if it is helpful. But if someone could show me how to put this code in terms of a Simulink system, I'm sure I could figure it out. FYI, if it isn't obvious, x is my input and y is my output.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it, but check out "If Action Subsystems" for one example of how to do it:

https://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ifactionsubsystem.html